# Is the Dart VM still used?

Tags: dart, flutter

I've been using dart/flutter for a few projects, and I'm really enjoying it.

I've read that when building a mobile app, dart builds a native app with native code. But I've also read that dart has its own VM for performance.

What I'm trying to understand is if that VM is what is used when you build a mobile app, or is it building other code that it compiles for the native app. And if its doing something else, what is the dart VM still used for?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Short answer: yes, Dart VM is still being used when you build your mobile app.

Now longer answer: Dart VM has two different operation modes a JIT one and an AOT one.

In the JIT mode Dart VM is capable of dynamically loading Dart source, parsing it and compiling it to native machine code on the fly to execute it. This mode is used when you develop your app and provides features such as debugging, hot reload, etc.

In the AOT mode Dart VM does not support dynamic loading/parsing/compilation of Dart source code. It only supports loading and executing *precompiled* machine code. However even precompiled machine code still needs VM to execute, because VM provides *runtime system* which contains garbage collector, various native methods needed for `dart:*` libraries to function, runtime type information, dynamic method lookup, etc. This mode is used in your deployed app.

Where does precompiled machine code for the AOT mode comes from? This code is generated by (a special mode of the) VM from your Flutter application when you build your app in the release mode.

You can read more about how Dart VM executes Dart code [here](https://mrale.ph/dartvm).

Comment: For flutter this answer appears to be false : https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/faq#how-does-flutter-run-my-code-on-android

Comment: @flchaux the answer is given exactly in the Flutter context. there is just a bit of confusion about what "VM" part of "Dart VM" means. The answer here explains that VM does not necessarily imply JITing.

Comment: JIT => just in time; AOT => ahead of time - for anyone else that didn't know that - just looked it up

Comment: Is there a way to get https://mrale.ph/dartvm/ full? I want to know more about the GC how it splits generations and when objects are promoted from the short lived memory, managed by the young scavenger GC technique to the longed lived one managed by the mark-sweep.

Answer (score 14):

When the Dart VM is used in release mode, it is not really a VM (virtual machine) in the traditional sense of a *virtual computer processor implemented in software*, which has its own machine language that is different from the hardware's machine language.

This is what causes the confusion in the original question. In release mode, the Dart VM is basically a runtime library (not much different than runtime libraries required by all high level languages).

Answer (score 0):

The Dart VM is perfectly good for server-side applications, particularly using `dart:io` to access local files, processes, and sockets.

Comment: Do you know if the VM is used in the mobile apps you build with flutter? That was the first question I asked.

Comment: On mobile the VM is used during development. Hot-reload wouldn't work with compiled code.

Comment: VM is used both when you develop and when you deploy the Flutter app.  VM is always there, its just configured differently depending on the use case. Dart VM is a swiss army knife, it slices and dices. See my answer below.

Comment: When I deploy for Flutter does the same dev VM instance get deployed (but with a prod configuration) or is it optimized and reduced?

Comment: @Ganymede it's a special build of Dart VM with all unused components stripped.

Comment: I have no idea what "special build" means

Comment: @Ganymede it is not the same as dev VM. it's a special version of a VM, optimized and reduced. ("special build" means it is was build in a special way... Dart VM is compiled from C++ sources and by tweaking some compilation options one gets different "builds")